# Django - 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable as i used user filter in context processors

Tags: python, django

I'm passing some kind of filter into the whole project using **context_processorts.py** but it only works when a user is logged in when there is no user logged in it returns an error. here are my files :

**context_processors.py**

```
def include_user_favs(request, user_favs=None):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        pass
    else:
        user_favs = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'user_favs': user_favs,
    }

    return (context)
```

and then included in **settings.py** like :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'fostania.context_processors.include_name_list',
                'fostania.context_processors.include_current_user',
                'fostania.context_processors.include_dress_need',
                'fostania.context_processors.include_all_ads',
                'fostania.context_processors.include_new_messages',
                'fostania.context_processors.include_user_favs',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

then that's how i used in my HTML

**home.html**

```
                               {% if user_favs %}
                      {% for item in user_favs %}
                  {% if item.item == dress %}
                                                      <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/star-yes.png' %}" title="مسح من  الفساتين المفضلة"></a>
{% else %}

                                <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/star_no.png' %}" title="إضافة إلى الفساتين المفضلة"></a>

                          {% endif %}
                          {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
                                              <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/star_no.png' %}" title="إضافة إلى الفساتين المفضلة"></a>
              {% endif %}
```

and here is the error and traceback :

`'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django_filters',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'fostania_web_app.apps.FostaniaWebAppConfig']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\python\Django\fostania\fostania_web_app\views.py" in home
  17.     user_favs = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user)

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  836.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  854.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1253.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1277.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1187.             self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in check_related_objects
  1052.                 for v in value:

File "C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  216.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The traceback is telling you that the error occurs on line 17 of `views.py`, which you haven’t shown. It looks as if you haven’t checked for anonymous users there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is_authenticated`.

[Read-only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) attribute which is always True (as opposed to AnonymousUser.is_authenticated which is always False)

```
def include_user_favs(request, user_favs=None):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_favs = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'user_favs': user_favs,
    }

    return (context)
```

Comment: Well, it didn't fix it to change `if request.user.is_anonymous:` to `if request.user.is_anonymous():` it returned an error `'bool' object is not callable`

Comment: Thanks, man your information led me to find out that I needed to call the request.user from only one place also needed to hide the button from an authed users and it worked

Comment: `login_required` is meant for views. It doesn't make sense to use it for a context processor like `include_user_favs`, which should always return a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, checking `user.is_authenticated` or `user.is_anonymous` are both fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @zimdero and @Alasdair i found that i've used the line `user_favs = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user)`
 in another view function so it is being called 2 times by `context_processors.py` and **views.py** which caused the error that is just **solved** after I removed it from the views.py